# How to implement 2 UITableViews in 1 ViewController? The tableViews each have their own custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 tableviews each with their own custom cell. How can I implement these tableviews in 1 viewcontroller? Here is my code.

Xcode can't cast the custom cell to the standard `UITableViewCell`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //        let accountSize = Int(accounts.count())
    //        return accountSize;

    var count:Int?

    if tableView == self.tableView {
        count = Int(accounts.count())
    }

    if tableView == self.tableViewLoan {
        count =  Int(loans.count())
    }

    return count!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //        return UITableViewCell()

var cell:UITableViewCell?        
if tableView == self.tableView {
        //cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AccountsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell
        var cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AccountsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell

        var account:SUVTISDDA = SUVTISDDA()
        account = accounts.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row))

        var accountType = ""
        var accountNum = ""

        let accountNumber = account.Description.Value
        var accountSplit = accountNumber.componentsSeparatedByString(": ")
        if(accountSplit.count > 1){
            accountNum = accountSplit[1]
            accountType = accountSplit[0]
            print("Account number: \(accountSplit[1])")
        } else {
            accountType = account.Description.Value
            accountNum = " No Account Number"
            print("Account number unavailable")
        }

        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle

        cell1.AccountTypeLabel!.text = accountType
        cell1.AccountNumberLabel!.text = accountNum
        cell1.AccountCurrencyLabel!.text = account.Currency.Value
        cell1.AccountAmountLabel!.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(account.AvailableBalance.Value)
        cell1.AccountTypeLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0.451, blue:0.682, alpha:1)

        return cell1
    }

    if tableView == self.tableViewLoan {
        var cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("loanCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LoanCell

        var loan: SUVTILN = SUVTILN();
        loan = loans.objectAtIndex(UInt(indexPath.row));

        cell2.descriptionLabel.text = loan.Description.Value;
        cell2.currencyLabel.text = loan.Currency.Value;
        cell2.[![valueLabel][1]][1].text = loan.LoanAmount.Value.stringValue;

        cell = cell2;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/An6G2.png

Comment: And it can't just be a single table with two sections?

Comment: You have a typo: `var cell:UITableView?` should be `var cell:UITableViewCell?`

Comment: nope still getting the same kind of error Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x107ccf540) to '.AccountsTableViewCell' (0x105487b18)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would configure two tableViews in one viewController (this can work with 2 or more tableViews).

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == yourFirstTableView {

        return yourFirstArray.count

    } else {

        return yourSecondArray.count

    }



}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == yourFirstTableView {

        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourFirstCellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourFirstCustomTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell for your first tableView


        return cell1


    } else {

        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourSecondCellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourSecondCustomTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell for your second tableView

        return cell2


    }

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if tableView == studentsTableView {

        // Perfrom action for your first tableView

    } else {

        // Perfrom action for your second tableView

    }

}
```

Comment: The cellForRowAtIndexPath gives me the error that it is missing the return function.

Comment: Are you returning cell1 and cell2 in the right spot?

Comment: I also updated my answer to reflect the fact that you are using a custom tableViewCell. Make sure that you have added the custom tableViewCell to the specific tableView in that storyboard or you will get a "not convertible to UITableViewCell" error.

Comment: The cellForRowAtIndexPath still gives me the same error that it's missing the return statement. The return is placed within the "if" but xcode tells me that the return should be placed before the closing bracket of the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of Xcode showing cellForRowAtIndexPath and the error to your question? You can use Command - Shift - 3 to take a screenshot of your Max's screen

Comment: Try like this   `-func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == yourFirstTableView {
        let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourFirstCellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourFirstCustomTableViewCell
        //Configure the cell for your first tableView
        return cell1
    }  else{
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourSecondCellReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourSecondCustomTableViewCell

        return cell2
    }
}`

Comment: Your code looks right. Try adding some code into the each of the functions and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Don't add **if condition to else** part.. It will work out

Comment: Yes, @Sakshi is correct! I forgot about that. Xcode sees that you don't have a fallback aka an else statement. I updated my answer.

Comment: removed the if and the error is gone, now I have another error that it cannot cast UITableViewCell to CustomTableViewCell

Comment: Ok so this probably is because you haven't hooked up your tableViewCells correctly. Check out this video: https://youtu.be/I87A99w_w2g

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do.  Maybe try using a ContainerViewController and embedding two TableViewControllers into that.  This should give the effect of having two TableViews in one ViewController but you will have separate files for each TableViewController.